# App force closes when using ActionBarSherlock on actual device, but works on emulator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am developing an app that uses the ActionBarSherlock and SherlockFragments in only some of the activities. When testing the app on the Android emulator through Eclipse, the app works perfectly. When running the signed and exported app on an actual phone though, only the activities that do NOT use Sherlock work. Whenever I launch an activity that uses Sherlock, the app force closes. I tested this on Android Gingerbread and ICS devices. The app's minimum SDK level is 7 (2.2) and the target SDK level is 15 (4.0.3). Any explanations or solutions?

Comment: Can you show the error logs given by the force close?

Comment: Yeah, can't do anything without a stack trace in this case.

Comment: Hi, how do you get a stack trace from a phone? The app works perfectly without error on the emulator through Eclipse, but when I install the apk on my phone and run the app, it force closes.

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful, but here is the LogCat output when I launch the SherlockFragmentActivity (the one that forces closes on my phone) on the emulator: http://pastebin.com/PJJ4D0VW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. While using Proguard, the following lines must be added to the Proguard config file to ensure functionality of the ActionBarSherlock library:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```